# Rounding/Truncate with MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Having trouble getting the following value to only display 2 decimal places after performing a division calculation. The purpose is to round E.Amount to the nearest .25. The formula does that but returns a value with 6 decimals rather than the desired 2.

Example values of E.Amount are 0.15, 0.02, 2.37

```
Round(E.Amount/25,2)*25
```

Other things I've tried

```
Round(Round(E.Amount/25,2)*25,2) -- Still returns 6 decimals
Cast (Round(E.Amount/25,2)*25) as Numeric (18,2) --returns a syntax error
```

Other variations of using cast have resulted in E.Amount be the subject of the cast which causes the value to be incorrect.

Comment: The syntax error is because you have a parenthese at the wrong place.  If you correct that it will do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
cast( Round(E.Amount/25,2)*25 as decimal(20,2) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it kind of manually with a case statement:

```
declare @value decimal(12,2) = 12.37

select Floor(@Value) 
    + case  when @value - Round(@value,0)<=.12 then 0
            when @value - Round(@value,0)<=.37 then .25
            when @value - Round(@value,0)<=.62 then .5
            when @value - Round(@value,0)<=.87 then .75
            else 1 end
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. Those were just some of the examples of what the value could be. The value could actually be any decimal from 0 - 40.